# Remove a gap between two divs after using float

Tags: html, css

I have been working on a collage for the last two days and I am facing a problem.

```css
body {
 width: 380px;
}

.featured-sellers-collage {
  width: 100%;
}

.featured-sellers-collage .div1 p {
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 float:left;
 width: 50%;
}
.featured-sellers-collage .div1 p img {
 
 width: 100%;
}

.featured-sellers-collage .div2 {
 flaot: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="featured-sellers-collage">
 <div class="div1">
      <p><img src="http://lorempixel.com/189/325/" alt="" /></p>
      <p><img src="http://lorempixel.com/189/325/" alt=""/></p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="div2">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/380/325/" alt="" />
  </div>

</div>
```

After running it you can see there is a gap between `div1` and `div2`.
Is there any way for me to remove it? (Gap between `div1` and `div2` should be equal to 0px).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: For `div2` your `float` property has a typo it's `flaot` when should be `float`

Comment: the p buy default has margin on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove margin from p tag

```
.featured-sellers-collage .div1 p {
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 float:left;
 width: 50%;
    margin:0;
}

.featured-sellers-collage .div1 p img {
 width: 100%;
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: Also I don't think `left` and `bottom` properties are doing anything unless the `<p>` is positioned absolute somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks @afelixj, It is working fine on Internet explorer 11, Firefox 37, Chrome 49, Opera, but the gap is still there on safari 5.1.7 on windows. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Two things are there because of which images are there

> 1. In `div1` image is in `<p>` tag and `<p>` tag has a default bottom margin u need to set it to 0

```
.featured-sellers-collage .div1 p {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
  margin-bottom:0;
}
```

> 2. `<img>` is inline tag and you need to set `display:block` to `<img>` to remove space bottom of image

```
.featured-sellers-collage .div1 p img {

    width: 100%;
  display:block
}
```

Here is the working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/yudi/nenu9chm/

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove P tag default margin and img default spacing by adding vertical-align: top;  and every thing will be fine

```css
body {
 width: 380px;
}

.featured-sellers-collage {
  width: 100%;
}

.featured-sellers-collage .div1 p {
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 float:left;
 width: 50%;
}
.featured-sellers-collage .div1 p img {
 
 width: 100%;
}
.featured-sellers-collage p{margin: 0;}
 .featured-sellers-collage img{vertical-align: middle;}

.featured-sellers-collage .div2 {
 flaot: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="featured-sellers-collage">
 <div class="div1">
      <p><img src="http://lorempixel.com/189/325/" alt="" /></p>
      <p><img src="http://lorempixel.com/189/325/" alt=""/></p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="div2">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/380/325/" alt="" />
  </div>

</div>
```